# Is it possible to shut down all antennae except for the gps?

Tags: gps, gps-tracking

I am thinking of buying an Android phone soon (Probably Desire HD), and would like to use it to record hiking trips GPS data.
All those run tracking apps seems just right to me, but I am looking for something that can run more than a few hours, so I figured that turning off the wifi/3g/cell antennae will give me a much longer battery life.
Is it possible to achieve it easily? Maybe only with root access?

Comment: Similar (but not duplicate) question here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/745/android-app-to-turn-off-cellphone-sim-radio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can activate the Airplane mode to shutdown everything (calls, wifi, etc), and then re-activate the GPS. Only the GPS Antenna will be activated... I think :D

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with a free app called quick settings. You don't need to root your phone. You should know that if you turn off your data, you won't have real time set to the maps, but you'll still be able to record your gps data. To get around that you can download offline maps app like maveric.  Ill add links to this answer later when I'm not driving  and using speech to text.

Comment: wow.. impressive that it's all written with speech to text.

Comment: If you must resort to answering while driving, I'll slow down some ;)

Comment: So THAT'S where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [APNDroid](http://www.appbrain.com/app/apndroid/com.google.code.apndroid) to toggle your data on/off.

Alternatively, if you still want data and have a SIM phone, you can force it use 2G only in the network settings.